# How to create incremental scripts to update database schemas using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I'm trying to use VS 2010 Sql Server Database Project to keep track on changes made on my database and to generate appropriate scripts when a change needs to be deployed from dev to production environment.

I have created my schema comparison between my dev database and the project schema which does a great job. However, I cannot find a way to create incremental scripts, the only things I get are scripts with CREATE statements (Export to Editor option).

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As part of our auto build process, we store .dbschema files for each environment in source control. During the build, we create the .dbschema file based on the database project and then use vsdbcmd command line call to generate the change script between the project schema and each destination DB schema. If you need specific command line call, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using "Data Dude" correctly, these are done for you and run when you choose Deploy. Just keep your schema (tables, stored procs, populate scripts etc) as a project item and change it as you need to. The build-and-deploy process will generate the scripts. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx is a not-bad starting point if you want to get these scripts and run them youself against various staging, production, etc databases.

Comment: That could work if I had sysadmin access to prod database but I don't. That is why I'm using the VS Project to store the DB state after deployments. So when we want to deploy changes we compare current database state to what is store on the project and generate scripts. The problem is that I don't get ALTER scripts only CREATE.

Answer (score 0):

In the .deploymentmanifest file there are two settings:

`<DeployToDatabase>False</DeployToDatabase>`

and

`<DeployToScript>True</DeployToScript>`

Running vsdbcmd will then generate the change scripts without affecting the target database. All you'd need is a version of the database which is the same as the production version, or access to point vsdbcmd at production to generate the script.

Comment: Can you confirm that there is a way to make `vsdbcmd` generate the `ALTER` statements (not the `CREATE` statements). I strongly suspect there isn't.